# Unable to run ZipKin server with spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, zipkin

Zipkin won't launch with spring boot.
When I run the application from the server side (java), it throws this exception (probably a dependency issue, but I can't find it). I have tried many ways to troubleshoot it and have changed the spring versions each time i ran into difficulties.):

It is necessary to start rabbitmq first?

What is the best way to launch zipkin in spring boot?

Why would it be a good idea to run Zipkin with spring boot?

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>zipkin-distributed-tracing-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>zipkin-distributed-tracing-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>zipkin-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>zipkin-autoconfigure-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Application.java

```
package com.example.zipkindistributedtracingserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import zipkin2.server.internal.EnableZipkinServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableZipkinServer
public class ZipkinDistributedTracingServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZipkinDistributedTracingServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=zipkin-distributed-tracing-server
server.port=9411

eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

ERROR

```
2022-06-07 11:37:48.608  WARN 4660 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [zipkin2.server.internal.InternalZipkinConfiguration]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class zipkin2.server.internal.ZipkinServerConfiguration
2022-06-07 11:37:48.612  INFO 4660 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-06-07 11:37:48.628 ERROR 4660 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.SpringApplication                  : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [zipkin2.server.internal.InternalZipkinConfiguration]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class zipkin2.server.internal.ZipkinServerConfiguration
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:610) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
```

Comment: did you try including spring-boot-starter-actuator ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy the zipkin jar under `src/main/resources`
2. ```
        <plugin>
             <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>1.0.1</version>
             <executions>
                 <execution>
                     <id>copy-file</id>
                     <phase>verify</phase>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>copy</goal>
                     </goals>
                     <configuration>
                         <sourceFile>src/main/resources/zipkin-server-2.22.1-exec.jar</sourceFile>
                         <destinationFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</destinationFile>
                     </configuration>
                 </execution>
             </executions>
         </plugin>
   ```